# Error in executing usbcam_node by using raspberrypi2 (indigo)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I 'd like to use usbcam_node in raspberrypi2.I have already installed indigo .
And  I installed somethings and execute some commands as following procedures.

(1)$ ls /dev/video*
->/dev/video0 is displayed.

(2)$ sudo apt-get update
(3)$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-usb-cam
(4)$ roscore
(5)$ rosparam set usb_cam/pixel_format yuyv
(6)$ rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node
(7)$ rostopic list
->/rosout
/rosout_agg
/usb_cam/camera_info
/ usb_cam/image_raw

(8)$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_raw

Then the window is appeared but the screen is gray and the error is appeared.

> [INFO][148578891.02916418]:Using transport "raw"
> /opt/ros/indigo/lib/image_view/image_view:symbol lookup error :/opt/ros/indigo/lib/image_view/image_view: undefined symbol :_ZN9cv_bridge18cvtColorForDisplayERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_7CvImageEEERKSsNS_25CvtColorForDisplayOptionE

Could you let me know how to  resolve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257051/error-in-executing-usbcam_node-by-using-raspberrypi2-(indigo)/) by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I really appreciated your help.

When I executed the following command, I succeded.

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-image-view
```

---

Originally posted by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) with karma: 104 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to be the same error described [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/228693/image_view-symbol-lookup-error/) and [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/215).

Should be fixed in latest image_view releases.

Anyway you can try to execute this

```
rostopic echo /usb_cam/image_raw
```

if the message in printed without errors you can be more confidential that the problem rely on image_view.

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1